# How to get the 10bit per pixel from a raw image file?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-requests, computer-vision

I have a 10bit .raw file which is coded into 8 bit. so after the 4 bytes, the 5th byte contains the 2 bits or each 4bytes. ( so total after decode I should get 10 bits per pixel).

raw file : <_io.TextIOWrapper name='img_10bit.raw' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

size of 1d array after reading using np.uint8 = (2611200,)

[check this image for the bits placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n6AB.png)

**How to get the 10 bit data per pixel to reconstruct the image? , i need to do this in python**.

Comment: If you want to share the file via Dropbox or GoogleDrive or somesuch, along with its height and width, I may have time to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Read four bytes and shift them left by two bits.

Read a fifth byte and slice it in four parts:

- "bitwise and" with 3;
- shift right by two bits.

Add the results of the "bitwise and" to the respective bytes and you get four 10 bits numbers.